# Get a list of user matching different terms with a specified ratio

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following simple document structure.

```
{ 
 username: string,
 hobby: string
}
```

I want to get, in one request, a list of users containg 80% of users with football as hobby, 10% with rugby, 5% with volley, 5% with tennis.
Is this possible ? How can you achieve that ?
If so, is it possible to say that i want a percentage of user with a random hobby value.

Thanks a lot, 
Julien

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Elasticsearch doesn't give you partially calculated result. You may have to pull the list of users with football as hobby, likewise pull users with rugby as hobby and pull users with tennis as hobby at your client side. Depending on your request, calculate percentage of users manually or at client side w.r.t count of total documents returned and select what you are looking for.

Comment: yep, that's what i'm going to do. i'm going to request the three bobbies in my request, and then sort everything as I want in the backend before sending it to my app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may have to create four requests, one each for pulling all users with football, all users with rugby, all users with tennis and then one more request to get total count of all documents in Elasticsearch. Then you may have to apply the logic in your client side. Not sure how you'd be able to do that in single request. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

**No. Elasticsearch does not give partially calculated results.**

- Another flaw is that the numbers might not match the exact percentage (in any database).
  For example, you have 4 users in total, one with each hobby you specified. So here you cannot achieve the desired list with exact percentage. And there are infinite possibilities of such combinations.
- Another improvement: If you have exactly this structure, consider Relational Database (like SQL).